# Lambda functions is hidden

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I created two lambda functions for Alexa a few weeks ago. In the last week I used and changed it. But today when I open my developer console I can't find it. Functions work fine, but list of my lambda functions is pure. What can happens?

Comment: Check that you are in the right region.

Comment: @j-u-s-t-i-n thanks you are right

Answer (score 1):

[Check that you are in the right region.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/getting-started.html#select-region)